# Install OpenNI 2 in ros fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I install OpenNI 2 in ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190131/install-openni-2-in-ros-fuerte/) by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

apt-get install libopenni2-dev should work for you.

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0